# Remote IO AudioBufferList Crash

Tags: ios, pointers, crash, remoteio

Why would the following bolded line crash???  Any suggestions?

```
static OSStatus AudioInputCallback(void *inRefCon,
                               AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                               const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                               UInt32 inBusNumber,
                               UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                               AudioBufferList *ioData) {

AudioUnitRender(audioUnitIn, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, 
inBusNumber, inNumberFrames, inputBufferList);

AudioSampleType is a signed short
**AudioSampleType (pointer)data = inputBufferList->mBuffers[0].mData;**
```

Comment: I dont see a bolded line...

Comment: Sorry, it's the last line there... with the ** around it.  Is maybe the way the data is being accessed inappropriate for some reason?